# Validate required multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am trying to validate multiselect dropdown as a required field. My form includes textboxes, dropdown and multiselect. since its long procedural form, i used next button to proceed to fill further details of form.
I am stuck at multiselect validation for next button. The next button is not showing multiselect as a required field.
I just want to ensure the multiselect is NOT empty and the user has made a choice.

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form-box" id="form-content">
                  <form role="form" action="index.php"  method="post" class="f1" id="myForm">

                    <h3 style="color: #000;">Registration</h3>


                    <div class="f1-steps">
                      <div class="f1-progress">
                          <div class="f1-progress-line" data-now-value="8" data-number-of-steps="6" style="width: 8%;"></div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                        <p>Basic Details</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="f1-step ">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
                        <p>Account Details</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                        <p>User Details</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="f1-step active">
                                <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></div>
                                <p>Additional Details</p>
                            </div>

                        <div class="f1-step">
                        <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></div>
                        <p>Payment Details</p>
                      </div>

                    </div>


                          <fieldset>
                            <h4>Select Media types</h4>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="media_type_ids">Select Media types </label>

                              <select id="mySel3" multiple="multiple" class="select2 btn btn-default form-control" name="media_type_ids[]" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 15px;" required>
                                    <optgroup label="Select multiple">
                                      <option value="8">Adware</option>
                                      <option value="26">Andriod-Mobile</option>
                                      <option value="3">Banner</option>                
                                   </optgroup>
                            </select>   
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label  for="vertical_category_ids">Select Vertical categories </label>

                              <select id="vertical_category_ids" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="vertical_category_ids[]" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">
                                 <option value=" ">Select Vertical categories </option>
                                <option value="16">Business & Finance</option>
                                <option value="26">Education</option>
                                <option value="49">Financial Products & Services</option>
                                <option value="57">Food & Drink</option>
                                <option value="66">Health, Beauty & Personal Care</option>
                                <option value="80">Home & Garden</option>


                            </select>

                            </div>

                         <div class="f1-buttons">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset>
                            <h4 style="color: #000;">Payment Details:</h4>
                            <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-date">Date</label>
                                  <input type="date" name="date_added" placeholder="Date..." class="f1-date form-control" id="f1-date">
                            </div> -->


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label  class="sr-only" for="payment_min_threshold">Payment Threshold</label>
                                 <select id="payment_min_threshold" class="form-control" name="payment_min_threshold" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 15px;" required>
                              <option value="">Select Payment Threshold</option>
                                  <option value="100.00">Send me payment above $100</option>
                                  <option value="200.00">Send me payment above $200</option> 

                            </select>
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="payment_to">Payment To</label>
                                 <select id="payment_to" class="form-control" name="payment_to" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 15px;" required >
                                    <option value="">Select Payment To</option>
                                  <option value="0">Payment to Company</option>
                                  <option value="1">Payment to Person</option>

                            </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="referral_notes" class="sr-only">Did anyone refered you to our website?</label>
                                <input type="text" name="referral_notes" placeholder="Did anyone refered you to our website? .." class="referral_notes form-control" id="referral_notes" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['referral_notes'])) echo $_POST['referral_notes']; ?>">
                            </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label  for="notes" class="sr-only">notes</label>
                                <textarea name="notes" placeholder="Which other networks do you work with?" 
                                                     class="notes form-control" id="notes" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['notes'])) echo $_POST['notes']; ?>"></textarea>
                            </div>

                          <div class="f1-buttons">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>

                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and my js is

```
    /*
    Form
*/

$('.f1 fieldset:first').fadeIn('slow');

$('.f1 input[type="text"], .f1 input[type="password"], input[type="email"] , input[type="url"], input[type="lurl"], .f1 textarea, .f1 select, .f1 select[i].value').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('input-error');
});

// next step
$('.f1 .btn-next').on('click', function() {

    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    // fields validation
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"],  textarea, select').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
    // fields validation

    if( next_step ) {
        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
            // change icons
            current_active_step.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active');
            // progress bar
            bar_progress(progress_line, 'right');
            // show next step
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
            // scroll window to beginning of the form
            scroll_to_class( $('.f1'), 20 );
        });
    }

});

// previous step
$('.f1 .btn-previous').on('click', function() {
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function() {
        // change icons
        current_active_step.removeClass('active').prev().removeClass('activated').addClass('active');
        // progress bar
        bar_progress(progress_line, 'left');
        // show previous step
        $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        // scroll window to beginning of the form
        scroll_to_class( $('.f1'), 20 );
    });
});


   // submit
$('.f1').on('submit', function(e) {

    // fields validation
    $(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], textarea, select').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
    // fields validation

});
```

I wonder, is there any way to put required validation on multiselect dropdown for next button of my form.

Can you guide me with best solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], textarea, select').each(function() {
         var inputvalue = $(this).val();
        if( inputvalue == "" || $.trim(inputvalue).length == 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for your reply but  Its not working. still form goes to next step.

Comment: Its working fine..  it is validates well with $('.f1 .btn-next').on('click', function()... Thanks a lot..